# Powerpoint with web browser - javascript only partially working

Tags: javascript, web, browser, powerpoint

we are organising a quiz next weekend, and I would like to integrate the scoreboard in the powerpoint. The scoreboard is exported to a html page with javascript, to scroll trough the table. When the page reaches the bottom, it refreshes (so it automatcally gets the latest version) and starts scrolling down again.

An example of the scoreboard is here : http://www.krikobea.be/quiz/scorebordPPS.html

As you can see, it works fine there. When at the bottom, it refreshes and starts scrolling down from the top again.

When I create a powerpoint presentation, I can add a web browser to a page and have it show the webpage. It even starts scrolling down, but when at the bottom, it just stops.

Can anyone please tell me how to fix this, either in the powerpoint or in the javascript?